# Installing ArcGIS Desktop correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.6, error-000210

I posted this on the ESRI technical support forum, but I figured I'd cross-post it here, too.  I'm trying to use ArcGIS 10.6 (Desktop Advanced) on a Windows 7 Pro machine.  However, something is obviously missing from my installation.  When I start up ArcMap, I get a pop-up error message saying "Error in LoadPlanXML.  Error number: 5 Description: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: type."  Otherwise, it appears to start up and work correctly, until I actually try to do anything.  Maps and data display normally.

When I attempt to use any of the tools in ArcToolbox, however, the execution always fails with error code 000210: Cannot create output.  Evidently, this is some type of non-specific error.  I have authorized and installed all extensions, so that's not the issue.  Basically, I can view and select layers and data on the map and in the table of contents, but I can't use any geoprocessing tools at all.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, as well as repairing the installation in Add/Remove Programs, with no luck.  It's very strange.

I originally upgraded from 10.1, but to make sure I didn't lose anything important, I found all the system directories with anything in their names related to ArcGIS or ESRI and moved them to a separate archive folder.  I then uninstalled 10.1 and installed 10.6, since you can't directly upgrade from one to the other.  I'm guessing that wasn't how I was supposed to do it, since I'm running into this problem now.

Comment: You may have harmed your Windows installation while trying to preserve data. You certainly didn't help the uninstall process by changing system folders around ***before*** uninstall. At this point I'd recommend reinstalling Windows before ArcGIS Desktop install.